# Where can I get those tips back that appear during installation?

Tags: installation

If you've installed Ubuntu yourself, you most probably remember that little "tour" offered during the installation.

Now being someone who recommends Ubuntu to a lot of users who have never tried linux before, I'd like to make those tips that were shown available to them, so they can have a look at it.

I remember there were some really nice tips like those about Askubuntu when you need to ask a question, or Ubuntu One to sync your files. These are just a few examples that new users are interested in, but when they start their Ubuntu, there's nothing telling them "Hey, did you know you can do this and that?"

If it's not possible to get these tips, do you know anything else that new users could use to "discover" their new OS?

Thank you in advance for the tips!

Answer (score 1):

Better yet, they can take the [**Ubuntu online tour**](http://www.ubuntu.com/tour/en/) and see the OS and the programs tips and graphical usability of Ubuntu.

Comment: Looks intresting indeed, thanks! However, although it's an excellent way to encourage hesitating windows-users, it doesn't really give tips to the "fresh" Ubuntu user (unless I've missed something): it mainly does what the users do on their real Ubuntu, if I got it right...